# Display mean plus or minus standard error of the mean

Tags: r, ggplot2, mean, standard-error

I was trying to represent a dot plot with my data, including all the dots and the mean +/- standard error of the mean (SEM). I build a new data frame, called "Descriptive" with the values of the mean and SEM, and I manage to represent the dots and the mean, but not the SEM as error bars. Could anyone help me providing some advice or sugesting any idea for the script?
I give you an example with iris data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
iris<- iris
SEM <- function(x){sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))}
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(MEAN=mean(Sepal.Length), SEM=SEM(Sepal.Length)) ->   
  Descriptive
print(Descriptive)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
  geom_point()+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, shape=95, size=8, color=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `stat_summary` function can handle all of this. The `fun` argument sets the middle value, but you can instead use the `fun.data` argument, with expects a dataframe with a ymin, y, and ymax value - letting it generate error bars:

```
SEM <- function(x){data.frame(y=mean(x),
                              ymin=mean(x)-sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)),
                              ymax=mean(x)+sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))}
```

Now we can just use this with `geom='errorbar'` to get what you want:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_point() +
    stat_summary(fun.data=SEM, color = 'red', geom='errorbar', width=0.2)
```

[image]

One other issue is that you've got a lot of overplotting. You might want to use geom_jitter instead:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_jitter(width=0.05) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=SEM, color = 'red', geom='errorbar', width=0.2)
```

[image]

Depending on what you want, you can play around with the different `geom`'s.

`"errorbar"`, used above, gives the nice bars, but doesn't have the mean marked on it's own (you'd need add the mean in as you did before separately:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_jitter()+
    stat_summary(fun=mean, shape=95, size=6, color=2) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=SEM, color = 'red', geom='errorbar', width=0.2)
```

[image]

`'pointrange'` gives a dot for mean + lines for the range. If you increase the `size` to make the line thicker, you need to reduce the `fatten` parameter, which makes the dot bigger than the line.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_jitter(width=0.05) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=SEM, color = 'red', geom='pointrange', size= 1, fatten=1)
```

[image]

`'crossbar'` gives a box with mean and error bars:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length))+
    geom_jitter(width=0.05) +
    stat_summary(fun.data=SEM, color = 'red', geom='crossbar', width=0.2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way. Use the `data` argument to `geom_errorbar` to pass the data set `Descriptive`. But this means you will have to change the rest of the `data` argument values in the other layers.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(
    data = iris, 
    mapping = aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  stat_summary(
    data = iris,
    mapping = aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length),
    fun=mean, shape=95, size=8, color=2) +
  geom_errorbar(
    data = Descriptive,
    mapping = aes(x = Species, ymin = MEAN - SEM, ymax = MEAN + SEM), 
    width = 0.2
  )
```

[image]